# How to join 3 Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have 3 tables:

1. Patient (id, name,age)
2. Check (no, id_patient, id_medic, illness, illness_status)
3. Medic (id, name, age)

So I want to list all Patient (name, age), Check data(Illness, status), and related Doctor order by patient.name

```
select patient.name, age, illness, illness_status from patient INNER JOIN check on patient.id = check.id_patient order by patient.name;
```

I can only get here, here the medic name does not appear, I am confused how to do it

```
+-----------+------+----------------------+----------------+
| name      | age  | illness              | illness_status |
+-----------+------+----------------------+----------------+
| Thomas    |   60 | Cough                | Normal         |
| Peter     |   60 | Flu                  | Normal         |
```

But I want to display like this,

```
name age illness     illness_status    medic.name
```

but I tried a different one, but still an error

```
select patient.name, age, illness, illness_status medic.name from patient LEFT JOIN check on patient.id = check.id_patient INNER JOIN doctor on check.id_medic = medic.id order by patient.name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another join. The table and column names in your query are not 100% consistent with your question, but that should be:

```
select p.name, p.age, c.illness, c.illness_status, m.name
from patient p
inner join check_up c on c.id_patient  = p.id
inner join medic m on m.id = c.id_medic
order by p.name;
```

Note that the use of table aliases (`p`, `c`, `m`) makes the query easier to read and write.